# Typescript Extension not building in VS, but works from Angular CLI

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

`src/shares/helpers/ArrayHelper.ts`

```
interface Array<T> {
    randomize(): this
}

Array.prototype.randomize = function () {
var array = this;
var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

// While there remain elements to shuffle...
while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
}

return array;
```

};

When I build and serve with Angular CLI `ng serve` it builds and serves.

When I try to build with Visual Studio it throws lots of errors about this file.

[image]

I have absolutely no idea what is happening or why. All I can say is that I think it is related to typscript versions - but everywhere I look I have 2.6.3 installed. I think that VS might be using something else but how do I confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out:
[image]
When I made the file I made a cs file and then renamed it. So it was somewhere in my .proj, trying to be compiled as a c# file.
I changed the build action to typescript and it worked.